# Overlaying one .svg image onto another without loss of transparency

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

graphic design noob here:

I have two plots that I have saved in the .svg format. One is a smaller plot, that I want to overlay on the larger plot. The border background of the smaller plot was set to transparent.

However, I notice when I copy and paste one image onto the other (in Adobe Illustrator for example), the smaller plot does not retain its transparency and has a white border background that blocks features of the larger plot.

What software could I use to overlay two .svg photos without losing transparency?

Thank you

Comment: If the svg files are *vector* and there is transparency, theres no reason a background should be *introduced* merely by a copy/paste operation. I'm afraid, at face value, this question is pretty difficult, if not impossible, to answer without at least some images as examples. (Note that svg is a "*container*" which *can hold* raster images so vector shouldn't be assumed.)

Comment: Is the image contained in the SVG vector or raster?  If raster, then what format is it? PNG/JPG or something else? Saving a raster image in SVG does not make it vector.  Please [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/127557/edit) and supply the missing information. Thanks.